# EF Core Will update an added entity and add it again(with different key) affect the previously added entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a notification system, after a new attendee joined an event, the event owner and all other participants will need to receive an notification.

Here is my code:

```
private void GenerateNitificationForEvent(Post theEvent, Attendee participant)
{
    var allPariticipants = theEvent?.Attendee;
    // For event owner 
    var notification = new Notification()
    {
        ApartmentId = theEvent.ApartmentId,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        HasRead = false,
        Message = string.Format(MyConstants.Notify_EventJoined_ForOwner, participant.User.Name, theEvent.Title, DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()),
        TargetUserId = theEvent.AuthorId,
        UserId = participant.UserId
    };

    _context.Notification.Add(notification);

    // For all participants
    var notificationsForAllParticipants = new List<Notification>();
    foreach(var attendee in allPariticipants)
    {
        notification.TargetUserId = attendee.UserId;
        notification.Message = string.Format(MyConstants.Notify_EventJoined_ForParticipants, participant.User.Name, theEvent.Title, DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
        notificationsForAllParticipants.Add(notification);
    }

    _context.Notification.AddRange(notificationsForAllParticipants);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am worrying about by modifying a already added entity and then treat it as a new entity to add into my context again, this approach will affected the previously added entity or have some unforeseen side effects.

Comment: May work, but there's a big chance that it will confuse EF's change tracker because you keep adding the same instance. Why not simply create new `Notification`s inside the loop?

Comment: Definitely won't work. For EF change tracker it's one and the same entity (the entities are identified by reference and key, and EF does not allow two references of the same entity type with the same key).  And once entity is tracked, the key cannot be mutated. As @Gert suggested, simply create `new` instances.

Comment: @Ivan I was a bit more cautious in my wording assuming that OP had run their code without any issues. Isn't that the least one can do when asking a question? But indeed I can't imagine EF to figure this out. I'm always a bit bemused when people ask questions about code they didn't try.